# AWS SCT error while connecting to PostgreSQL 13.4

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, data-migration, aws-sct

I get the following error when trying to connect to postgres as a target using AWS SCT:

```
LOADER ERROR: Error executing 'load-contexts' query: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "aws_oracle_context.context" does not exist'
```

It appears to occur on the LOADER step `load-contexts` 
All steps for LOADER until that point executed successfully per the log file.

Why would it be looking for a relation that appears to be related to oracle? 
Referenced relation triggering error: `aws_oracle_context.context`

Postgres RDS version: `13.4` 
AWS SCT version: `1.0.660` 
Postgres JDBC Driver: `42.3.3` and `42.2.19`

Any ideas / insight would be appreciated!

Comment: The 'Test connection' option in the 'Add target' pop-up window in SCT works, this error occurs when you select 'Connect' on that same pop-up window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the fix is to un-check `Server Level Objects` completely for the PostgreSQL connection you create under the `Servers` drop-dwon on the right hand side of the SCT interface.

It's selected by default when you connect so the tool will always fail on that job step for PostgreSQL it seems. Other aspects of the tool seem to work fine.

If anyone has anymore insight into this, feel free to share!